# Error on URL param after enable PrettyUrl

Tags: yii2

I have the following `DropDownList` where I select the category to update the graph. Everything was working fine until I enable "`enablePrettyUrl`".

Now when I select any value in the DropDownList appears the error

> "Not Found (# 404)".

What could be wrong?

**VIEW:**

```
<?php 
                $this->registerJs('var submit = function (val){if (val > 0) {
                    window.location.href = "' . Url::to(['/dashboard/accomplishment']) . '&category_id=" + val;
                }
                }', View::POS_HEAD);

                echo Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'category_id', ArrayHelper::map(Category::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id])
                            ->orderBy("desc_category ASC")
                            ->all(), 'id_category', 'desc_category'), ['onchange'=>'submit(this.value);','prompt'=>Yii::t('app','Select'),'class'=>'form-control']);
                ?>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public function actionAccomplishment()
    {
        $model = new Dashboard();

        $url = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('category_id');
        $category_id = isset($url) ? $url : 0;
        $thisyear  = date('Y');
        $thismonth = date('m');
        $user    = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
```

**My urlManager:**

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'rules' => array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
],
```

Comment: try changing the ampersand (&) to a question mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way work: 
`window.location.href = "' . Url::to(['/dashboard/accomplishment']) . '?category_id=" + val;`

Answer (score 1):

try  adding   `/` and removing &  this way

```
window.location.href = "' . Url::to(['/dashboard/accomplishment/']) . 'category_id=" + val;
```

Comment: url look like this: `dashboard/accomplishment?category_id=202`, was not so beautiful. To improve the URL?